# Why doesn't my C program play ASCII sound?

Tags: c, audio, ascii

I have a little problem - I'm doing exercises from Prata's book about C.
The exercise wants me to play a sound using printf function. The code of sound is '7' or '\a'. But unfortunately it doesn't work (I hear only deadly silence) and I can't figure out why. Other symbols (\n, \t etc. work correctly).
I'm using Linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void playASCIISound(void);

int main() {
    playASCIISound();
    printf("Напуганная внезапным звуком, Вика вскрикнула:\nЧто это было?????\n");
    return 0;
}

void playASCIISound(void) {
    printf("\a");
}
```

I tried to enable "Terminal bell" but it still has no effect :(
[image]

Comment: The interpretation of special characters is up to the specific console

Comment: Forget this sound stuff, it depends on the terminal/console, and playing a sound with `printf("\a");` is really a thing of the past.

Comment: Can you play other sounds, e.g. music on the computer? Have you flushed the buffer?

Comment: Computers used to have a simple bleeper on the main board, but now it usually has to be routed through the OS audio output. It depends on the shell implementation.

Comment: (My bad: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_code_chart)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Easy to confuse the C escape characters with escape codes (sich as `\a` vs `\xa`)

Comment: Yes, other sounds work, e.g. youtube videos.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - Not quite sure what you're saying there. According to the link, `\a` is a C control character escape for character 7, which is the BEL character. (As distinct from the hex code `\xa`, more commonly written `\n`. :-D )

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Re “The interpretation of special characters is up to the specific console”: The C implementation is responsible for ensuring an audible or visible alert is presented, per C 2018 5.2.2 2, which specifies the character `\a` is intended to produce “an audible or visible alert without changing the active position.”

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This is exactly what I meant, that two distinct escape sequences can be confused for being each other

Comment: @EugeneSh. - Got it. :-) In my case, it's more tragic than that: I just misremembered BEL as 8 rather than 7! :-D

Comment: @EricPostpischil How a C implementation can ensure an audible alert on a device incapable of producing audible alerts? Such as teletype or even a serial console?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Teletypes had mechanical *Bells*!  That's why ASCII 0x07 is called "BEL".

Comment: @EugeneSh.: A C implementation consists of the entire translation and execution environments, including hardware. If a teletype or serial console cannot produce an audible or visual alert, it cannot properly be used for a display device in a C implementation. But I used teletypes and consoles that could ring or beep.

Comment: It doesn't work on Linux Terminal, but it works for example if I compile and run this program using online C compiler :) And has a nice sound.
So, yeah, the issue is in Linux Terminal :(

Comment: @EricPostpischil So a console which is incapable of producing sound can be considered "improper C implementation", but it still can exist and be the "specific console" which is not interpreting the character properly. And there are enough examples of such (perhaps teletype was a bad one though)

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Yes, and if you wire up the computer to an elephant, it will not be a proper C implementation either. So what? It has nothing to do with OP’s question. Plenty of things exist that are neither proper C implementations nor anything that OP is using or asking about.

Comment: I tried to enable "Terminal bell" in Terminal preferences, but it still has no effect :(

Comment: @EricPostpischil It has to do everything with OP question, as they obviously are using an execution environment incapable of producing sound on the `BEL` output.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: It is not likely incapable of producing sound. It may be turned off, their system volume may be turned down, their speaker may be broken, etc. It is not likely because “The interpretation of special characters is up to the specific console.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'd argue that any of these reasons *is* driving the system incapable of producing sound in this specific configuration. But that is not my point. My point is that you might have a very sophisticated terminal software, fully supporting C execution environment requirement, it still can have a little switch to turn off the sound - which will make it "a console which is not interpreting certain special character".

Comment: Which terminal are you using? Your question can rather be, _why does my XXX terminal not produce an audible BEL?_

Comment: Linux Mint 20.2 Cinnamon